# Javascript Cross domain not consistent

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am trying to make a plugging using JS. 
I have the following code :

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.src = "js/index.js";
document.documentElement.appendChild(fileref);
```

I can verify that the code loads across domain however it doesn't always execute. Even if I set it before `</head>`

Sometimes it does but sometimes it just doesn't. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript is sometimes running before the `document.documentElement` exists. So when it goes to append the new `script` element, it fails. The inconsistency ("sometimes it does but sometimes it just doesn't") is due to the page rendering at ever-so-slightly different speeds.

**Update:**

Put this in your `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var scrpt = document.createElement('script');
        scrpt.type = 'text/javascript';
        scrpt.async = true;
        scrpt.src = 'js/index.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(scrpt, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to overcome that?  I tried adding window.onload = function() {} but that didn't help

Comment: thanks @Justin I have previously tried that but it does not even inject the script tag in my page.. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: @salmane: I know that code works. If you just put a `<script src='js/script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>` in your head, does it work? Are you sure the script has any events that trigger?